# Pandas Count number of previous rows based on column value and condition

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas I am trying create a column that counts all previous rows based on two column values.

The idea is to sort the data by animal and by date and then use pandas shift function to calculate the variance between an animals current date and previous date(the sample data below already has this done).

Then I want to create a new column called `Previous_Count` that is a rolling count of previous records based on value in `Animal` column and resets if the `Date_Variance` field is larger than `10`.

Sample Data Code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['2021-01-01','2021-01-05','2021-01-10','2021-01-11','2021-01-04','2021-01-08','2021-01-20','2021-01-21','2021-01-25','2021-02-12','2021-02-14'],
        'Date_Variance': [0,4,5,1,0,4,0,1,4,18,2],
        'Animal': ['Dog','Dog','Dog','Dog','Cat','Cat','Lizard','Lizard','Lizard','Lizard','Lizard'],
        #'Previous_count': [0,1,2,3,0,1,0,1,2,0,1]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Sample Data Output with `Previous_Count` column:

```
Date       Date_Variance    Animal  Previous_count
1/1/2021    0               Dog     0
1/5/2021    4               Dog     1
1/10/2021   5               Dog     2
1/11/2021   1               Dog     3
1/4/2021    0               Cat     0
1/8/2021    4               Cat     1
1/20/2021   0               Lizard  0
1/21/2021   1               Lizard  1
1/25/2021   4               Lizard  2
2/12/2021   18              Lizard  0
2/14/2021   2               Lizard  1
```

Comment: Why do the `Lizard` last two rows have 0 and 1? Shouldn't it be 3, 4

Comment: @MayankPorwal The count resets where Date_Variance > 10

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
grouper = df.groupby("Animal")["Date_Variance"].apply(lambda x: x.gt(10).cumsum())
df["Previous_count"] = df.groupby(["Animal", grouper]).cumcount()

>>> df
          Date  Date_Variance  Animal  Previous_count
0   2021-01-01              0     Dog               0
1   2021-01-05              4     Dog               1
2   2021-01-10              5     Dog               2
3   2021-01-11              1     Dog               3
4   2021-01-04              0     Cat               0
5   2021-01-08              4     Cat               1
6   2021-01-20              0  Lizard               0
7   2021-01-21              1  Lizard               1
8   2021-01-25              4  Lizard               2
9   2021-02-12             18  Lizard               0
10  2021-02-14              2  Lizard               1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html). Here we use [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to get a new group whenever `Date_Variance` is greater than 10

```
df['Previous_count'] = df.groupby(['Animal',
                                   df['Date_Variance'].gt(10).cumsum()]).cumcount()

print(df)

          Date  Date_Variance  Animal  Previous_count
0   2021-01-01              0     Dog               0
1   2021-01-05              4     Dog               1
2   2021-01-10              5     Dog               2
3   2021-01-11              1     Dog               3
4   2021-01-04              0     Cat               0
5   2021-01-08              4     Cat               1
6   2021-01-20              0  Lizard               0
7   2021-01-21              1  Lizard               1
8   2021-01-25              4  Lizard               2
9   2021-02-12             18  Lizard               0
10  2021-02-14              2  Lizard               1
```

---

```
print(df['Date_Variance'].gt(10).cumsum())
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     1
10    1
Name: Date_Variance, dtype: int64
```